# External click tracking links through img tags

Tags: php, click, tracking

Anyone know a good external link tracking script ? IE. to catch links and referrer stats through a posted img tag, even if there's no actual IMG. I know how PHP works in this matter, but I'd hate to code it from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the referrer via the built-in `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` variable. So use that in the php page that your link/image refers to. Then just have some code on that same php page to stick it where you need it via insertion to a database, or whatever other method you prefer.

Comment: Doesn't help a lot. Anyone else ?

Answer (score 1):

Just a note: If you create the image file with php, don’t waste your users bandwidth and return a 204 status code (no content) instead of a real image.

Answer (score 0):

With [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) you automatically get referrer information, visitor locations, pageviews, and much more. That's probably much easier than coding your own solution. If Google isn't your cup of tea, there are [plenty of other solutions](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2009/03/26/10-web-analytics-packages-for-tracking-your-visitors/).

Add some [special setup](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=72712) and you can track outbound links from your own pages as well.

Comment: This doesn`t help at all since it not related to my issue, since I need to be able to post in forums, and put a tracking pixel inside. This is what I want to build.